# Como manipular data em HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou pensando em um esquema, mas não sei como fazer e é simples.
Eu preciso fazer o seguinte cálculo:

Dia e Mês x Mês e Dia, exemplo, data de hoje:

```
Dia: 16
Mês: 07
x (vezes)
Mês: 07
Dia: 16
```

Em uma calculadora vai ficar assim: `1607*716 = 1150612`

Apenas isso, fazer este calculo sempre com a data atual que está na máquina e exibir o valor do resultado.

Existe como fazer isso no HTML?

Comment: Não, HTML é apenas uma linguagem de marcação. Você vai precisar usar JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, mas tem algum script que faça isso, que eu possa incluir?

Answer (score 1):

Apenas com HTML não vai rolar de você manipular dados dessa forma.

O que você pode fazer é um script muito simples:

```
<script>
  var atual = new Date();
  var dia = atual.getDate().toString();
  var mes = (atual.getMonth() + 1).toString();

  document.write(parseInt(dia+mes) * parseInt(mes+dia));
</script>
```

Isso deve funcionar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Com Javascript você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = '' + date.getDate();
var month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1);

day = day.length == 1 ? '0' + day : day;
month = month.length == 1 ? '0' + month : month;

var result = parseInt(day + month) * parseInt(month + day);
```

Comment: Cara, deu certinho!!!

Comment: Valeu mesmo! ficou perfeito